# While loop to check registry for value and then run an exe file

Tags: powershell, while-loop, exe

I'm trying to write a while-loop that will check the registry for a value and continue checking until found. Once found I wan't it to run an executable located on a network share then stop the loop. So far I can get it to look for the value in the registry and then run the executable, but it keeps running the executable over and over and I'm not sure how to get it to break after running the executable.

Here's my code so far:

```
$regkey = 'HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\FolderPath'
$name = 'Test'
$exists = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

While ($true) {
    if (($exists -ne $null) -and ($exists.Lenght -ne 0)) {
        & \\NETWORKSHARE\FolderName\Executable.exe -parameter -parameter "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderName\JavaScriptObject.json" -parameter
        } else {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, first it would be better to make it a DO {} WHILE {} loop so it is forced to the the test and continue testing until true, and second the loop continues indefinitely without doing anything in your example because it is only continually testing whether or not `$exists` was true when it entered the while loop.  To re-test the true/false status of `$exists` you have to reassign it at the beginning of your loop each time you run the loop.

```
$regkey = 'HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\FolderPath'
$name = 'Test'
$Notdone = $true

DO {
    $exists = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if (($exists -ne $null) -and ($exists.Lenght -ne 0)) {
        & \\NETWORKSHARE\FolderName\Executable.exe -parameter -parameter "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderName\JavaScriptObject.json" -parameter

    $Notdone = $false
    }
    else {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
    }
} While ($Notdone)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the condition you're waiting on is met, you want to stop looping.  Use the [`break` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break) to immediately jump to the next statement outside the loop:

```
$exists = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

While ($true) {
    if (($exists -ne $null) -and ($exists.Length -ne 0)) {
        & \\NETWORKSHARE\FolderName\Executable.exe -parameter -parameter "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderName\JavaScriptObject.json" -parameter
        break
    } else {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
    }
}
```

By the way, the loop above will only work if the registry value exists before the loop is entered; otherwise it will get stuck in an infinite loop because the value of `$exists` never changes inside the loop.  Instead, you need to reevaluate the condition on each iteration:

```
While ($true) {
    $exists = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (($exists -ne $null) -and ($exists.Length -ne 0)) {
        & \\NETWORKSHARE\FolderName\Executable.exe -parameter -parameter "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderName\JavaScriptObject.json" -parameter
        break
    } else {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
    }
}
```

You can simplify the code slightly by starting the executable outside of the loop and omitting the `else` branch:

```
While ($true) {
    $exists = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (($exists -ne $null) -and ($exists.Length -ne 0)) {
        break
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
}

& \\NETWORKSHARE\FolderName\Executable.exe -parameter -parameter "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderName\JavaScriptObject.json" -parameter
```

An even more concise but slightly less readable version would be this:

```
While (($exists = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null -or $exists.Length -eq 0) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
}

& \\NETWORKSHARE\FolderName\Executable.exe -parameter -parameter "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderName\JavaScriptObject.json" -parameter
```